# How to avoid the "Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement."

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, edmx

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application which uses Entity Framework version 6.

Now I develop the application on SQL Server 2012 inside my development server. I mapped my database tables and I generate the `.edmx` model file. Everything is working well on my development server.

Now when I deployed the application on our live server which uses SQL Server 2008, I got the following exception:-

> Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

on the following code inside my action method:-

```
records.Content = await db.SalesDatas.Where(x=>
                (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentdomainfilter) || x.EmailDomain.ToLower().Contains(currentdomainfilter.ToLower().Trim()))
                &&
                (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentgatewayfilter) || x.EmailGateway.ToLower().Contains(currentgatewayfilter.ToLower().Trim()))
                ).OrderBy(sort + " " + sortdir)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize.Value)
                    .Take(pageSize.Value).ToListAsync();
```

I find this link which describe the problem and how to fix it http://erikej.blogspot.ro/2014/12/a-breaking-change-in-entity-framework.html.

so I did the following inside my ASP.NET MVC project:

1. I edit the `.edmx` file.
2. I changed the value of `ProviderManifestToken` from 2012 to 2008

Now my application is working well on SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2008.

My question is whether the fix I applied is the correct way or it is a workaround. I mean is there a way I can force the `.edmx` to apply `OFFSET..FETCH` if the underlying SQL Server version is 2012, and to avoid this if the SQL Server version is 2008? The approach I followed to fix this issue (changing the value of `ProviderManifestToken` from 2012 to 2008), I will be eliminating any new features found in SQL Server 2012 (such as the use of `OFFSET..FETCH`), and have my `.edmx` only uses the features available in 2008..

Comment: That currently is the only way to solve this issue - you have to set the `ProviderManifestToken` to the lowest SQL Server version your app with EF needs to support.

Comment: IMO you should switch to key-based paging, instead of relying on regular paging. Say the end of your page is key `X` and there are `Y` rows in a page, then next page is `SELECT TOP Y ... FROM <table> WHERE key>X`. No clue how that translates to ASP.NET though, I can only speak to the SQL Server angle of this question.

Comment: The `.edmx` file(s) are built at compile time and this means you can't change this behavior at run time. **If** you wanted to support multiple sql server versions you would have to create 1 release package per sql server version you want to support. This would involve updating the `ProviderManifestToken` to the appropriate version before each compilation and deploying the correct version to the client(s)/server(s). You *could* also handle this with multiple code branches, one per sql server version (*which would be a PITA IMO*).

Comment: The bigger question is why you're developing on a platform different than the deployment. That's a recipe for all kinds of disaster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.edmx` file content is built at compile time and this means you can't change this behavior at run time.

This means you have 2 choices.

1. Point to the lowest Sql Server version you want to use as already pointed out by [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302) in the comments. This is the solution you are already using and it is not a work around but just the way this works.
2. *If* you wanted to support multiple Sql Server versions in your application you would have to create 1 release package per Sql Server version you want to support. A release package could be the replacement of a `dll` if the `.edmx` file is contained in a seperate project or perhaps the entire application if you just have one MVC project. This would involve updating the `ProviderManifestToken` to the appropriate version before each compilation and deploying the correct version to the client(s)/server(s).

Comment: so mainly i will need to have two versions of the edmx one for sql 2012 while the other for 2008 ??

Comment: @johnG - It depends on how you want to manage the change. You could use a build script to change the value at compile time (*this would be my choice if I had to do this*). You could also have 2 .edmx files that you keep in sync although that would require a lot of maintenance and other problems like how does the code know which one to use.

Comment: @johnG - I would keep the .edmx in a separate project and compile 2 versions of it (*again, using a build script)*. You could then deploy the correct .DLL based on the environment as a part of your deployment.

Comment: @johnG - I hope I answered your question to your satisfaction? If not please let me know.

Comment: @johnG - If you have no more questions could you award the bounty? If you do not the recipient is chosen based on the highest score but only 1/2 the points are awarded which can be frustrating for those that took their time to answer the question. Of course it makes no difference to the person that created the bounty as the full bounty amount is always deducted either way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @johnG - for the next time should you offer another bounty: You can always mark an answer as Answer (what you just did) and if the bounty time expires that answer gets the full bounty. You can always change the marked answer at any time (or unmark it entirely). That way you do not have to worry about the expiration time.